# why my python file can run in IDEL but can not in Eclipse?

Tags: python, eclipse

I am just learning Python with Programming Python,and when I run some examples in this book in Eclipse,there comes with a lot of error warning,and I can't run them successfully.But when I run them in IDEL3,they works.There are two files ,one is initdata.py ,another is makefile.py.
Here is the makefile.py'code:

```
dbfilename = 'people-file'
ENDDB  = 'enddb.'
ENDREC = 'endrec.'
RECSEP = '=>'

def storeDbase(db, dbfilename=dbfilename):
    "formatted dump of database to flat file"
    dbfile = open(dbfilename, 'w')
    for key in db:
        print(key, file=dbfile)                               
        for (name, value) in db[key].items():
            print(name + RECSEP + repr(value), file=dbfile)
        print(ENDREC, file=dbfile)
    print(ENDDB, file=dbfile)
    dbfile.close()

def loadDbase(dbfilename=dbfilename):
    "parse data to reconstruct database"
    dbfile = open(dbfilename)
    import sys
    sys.stdin = dbfile
    db = {}
    key = input()
    while key != ENDDB:
        rec = {}
        field = input()
        while field != ENDREC:
            name, value = field.split(RECSEP)
            rec[name] = eval(value)
            field = input()
        db[key] = rec
        key = input()
    return db

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from initdata import db
    storeDbase(db)
```

and this is the code of initdata.py:

```
bob = {'name':'Bob Smith','age':42,'pay':30000,'job':'dev'}
sue ={'name':'Sue Jones','age':45,'pay':40000,'job':'hdw'}
tom = {'name':'Tom','age':50,'pay':0,'job':None}
db = {}
db['bob']=bob 
db['sue']=sue 
db['tom']=tom 
if __name__=='__main__':
    for key in db:
        print(key ,'=>\n',db[key])
```

There is always an error warning in  "from initdata import db" which say that it is a unresoloved import:db.
But when I run these two file,there is nothing wrong.So,what is wrong with me ?My operation system is Ubuntu.

Comment: You've probably got your `PYTHONPATH` or your current working directory set wrongly. Try executing Eclipse from a different directory (or quick using it altogether, IDLE should be sufficient for hacking Python).

Answer (score 0):

This indentation in initdata.py looks wrong.

```
db['tom']=tom 
    if __name__=='__main__':
```

Try to undindent whole `if __name__...db[key])` block.

Comment: I am sorry for that to post the initdata.py wrong.It is all right for initdata.py